# Foreach iteration only returning last value from last loop

Tags: php, iteration

I'm trying to grab and count all the replies for each post for example all the replies for a specific post are labeled `2` under the column `level` but my foreach loop only grabs the value from the last iteration. For, example lets say I want all the comment replies from `post_id` `91` which has the comments `92` `95` for their `post_id` which in turn has the replies `93` `94` `96` for their `post_id`. My foreach loop only returns the last replies `post_id` `96` but I want my foreach loop to save all the posts comments replies post ids for example, it should return all the post ids `93` `94` `96`. I was wondering what do I need to change in my code to achieve this please help. Thanks.

MySQL Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
post_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
parent_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
member_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
profile_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
level INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
post LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
date_created DATETIME NOT NULL,
date_updated DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
update_count INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (post_id)
);
```

MySQL Table Data

```
post_id     parent_id   member_id   profile_id  level   post                    date_created            date_updated    update_count
96          95          1           1           2       reply 1 for comment 2   2017-08-06 02:26:09     NULL            0
95          91          1           1           1       comment 2               2017-08-06 02:25:43     NULL            0
94          92          1           1           2       reply 2                 2017-08-06 02:25:09     NULL            0
93          92          1           1           2       reply 1                 2017-08-06 02:25:00     NULL            0
92          91          1           1           1       comment 1               2017-08-06 02:24:47     NULL            0
91          0           1           1           0       post 1                  2017-08-06 02:24:31     NULL            0
```

PHP

```
//grab the all the post comments replies
function grab_all_post_comment_replies_parent_ids($post_id){
    //filter string to contain only numbers just in case
    $post_id = filter_numbers($post_id);
    //escape special characters in the string for use in the MySQL statement
    $post_id = mysqli_real_escape_string(database(), $post_id);

    $query = "SELECT `posts`.`post_id`
              FROM `posts` 
              WHERE `parent_id` = '$post_id'
              AND `level` = '1'";
    //short hand if statement ? if-true : if-false to determine the number of results returned by the query                                          
    $count = ($query = mysqli_query(database(), $query)) ? mysqli_num_rows($query) : 0; 

    if($count === 0){
        //query returned 0 meaning no results so return false as the value for the function
        return false;
    } else {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
            $results[] = $row['post_id'];
        }

        return $results;
    }
}


function all_post_comment_replies($post_id){
    $total = count(grab_all_post_comment_replies_parent_ids($post_id)); 
    $sum = 0;
    $all_ids = array();
    if(is_array(grab_all_post_comment_replies_parent_ids($post_id))){
        foreach(grab_all_post_comment_replies_parent_ids($post_id) as $parent_id){
            //filter string to contain only numbers just in case
            $parent_id = filter_numbers($parent_id);
            //escape special characters in the string for use in the MySQL statement
            $parent_id = mysqli_real_escape_string(database(), $parent_id);

            $query = "SELECT *
                      FROM `posts`
                      WHERE `parent_id` = '$parent_id'
                      AND `level` = '2'";
            //short hand if statement ? if-true : if-false to determine the number of results returned by the query                                          
            $count = ($query = mysqli_query(database(), $query)) ? mysqli_num_rows($query) : 0; 

            if($count === 0){
                //query returned 0 meaning no results so return false as the value for the function
                return false;
            } else {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
                    $ids[] = $row['post_id'];
                }

                $all_ids = $ids;
            }

            if($sum = $total){
                return $all_ids;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

            $sum++;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're running the query each loop. Thus, every loop, it's only ever going to get the first result from the query.

Comment: @Toastrackenigma how can I fix this problem?

Comment: OK, so your code is a bit of a mess and almost definitely not done right. What are you trying to do - like, what ***should*** `all_post_comment_replies` echo / return?

Comment: it should just return all the post ids for the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

In the `foreach` loop, you looped while `$parent_id` was in `grab_all_post_comment_replies_parent_ids($post_id)`. However, what you forgot was that at the end of each loop, the condition in the `foreach` loop is checked again.

Thus, every time the `foreeach` loop ended, you called that function again, it replaced the current array with the new one, and thus we're searching through a new array from the start, and thus you only got the first result.

What I have done here is run the function once at the start, and then store it to a variable. Now it will loop through each value in the array without a problem.

Secondly, there is no need for the bit where you check the sum and its total. The `foreach` loop will always end, and you can return the values when it does. At the moment though, you are simply checking is `0 == total`, which it will not be, and then returning without giving your loop a chance to keep running.

Simply remove it, and return at the end.

### The Solution

```
function all_post_comment_replies($post_id){
    $parent_ids = grab_all_post_comment_replies_parent_ids($post_id);
    $total = count($parent_ids); 
    $all_ids = array();
    if(is_array($parent_ids)){
        foreach($parent_ids as $parent_id){
            //filter string to contain only numbers just in case
            $parent_id = filter_numbers($parent_id);
            //escape special characters in the string for use in the MySQL statement
            $parent_id = mysqli_real_escape_string(database(), $parent_id);

            $query = "SELECT *
                      FROM `posts`
                      WHERE `parent_id` = '$parent_id'
                      AND `level` = '2'";
            //short hand if statement ? if-true : if-false to determine the number of results returned by the query                                          
            $count = ($query = mysqli_query(database(), $query)) ? mysqli_num_rows($query) : 0; 

            if($count === 0){
                //query returned 0 meaning no results so return false as the value for the function
                return false;
            } else {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
                    $ids[] = $row['post_id'];
                }

                $all_ids = $ids;
            }

        }
        return $all_ids;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @juice.gin What do they say?

Comment: I meant to say that the code just does the same thing my posted code does. It does not return all the replies post ids.

Comment: @juice.gin There. Found another bug in it. Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

In the function all_post_comment_replies() there are this error :

```
if($sum = $total){ // assigment, not comparison
                return $all_ids;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
```

In if sentence, the $total variable is assigned to $sum.
No comparison expression and is always true ($sum is always >0), it's only false when expression is equal to zero.
I think it iterate only one time. 
Fix with :

```
if($sum == $total){ // see ==
                return $all_ids;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: This did not grab all the replies post ids.